# How to create chrome like tab on Electron

Tags: electron

I am making a desktop application using Github Electron, and want to know how can I make chrome like tabs.

Like when we open any browser or let say chrome, we can add create new tab on the same window, likewise I want this to be done in my desktop app. I dig on electron doc's and community packages but find nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Found [this thing](https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-tabs). The documentation is surprisingly scarse. But when you look into the index.html, it's quite easy.
Just put

```
<div class="chrome-tabs">
    <div class="chrome-tabs-content"></div>
    <div class="chrome-tabs-bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.chrome-tabs');
var chromeTabs = new ChromeTabs();
chromeTabs.init(el, { tabOverlapDistance: 14, minWidth: 45, maxWidth: 243 });
```

And it's done.

---

## EDIT

#### Additional information

To use chrome-tabs you need to include draggabilly and chrome-tabs:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/draggabilly@2.1.1/dist/draggabilly.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chrome-tabs.js"></script>
```

And you might be interested in additional event listener:

```
el.addEventListener('activeTabChange', ({ detail }) => console.log('Active tab changed', detail.tabEl))
el.addEventListener('tabAdd', ({ detail }) => console.log('Tab added', detail.tabEl))
el.addEventListener('tabRemove', ({ detail }) => console.log('Tab removed', detail.tabEl))
```

## END OF EDIT

---

To add tab:

```
chromeTabs.addTab({
      title: 'New Tab',
      favicon: 'demo/images/default-favicon.png'
    });
```

To remove tab:

```
chromeTabs.removeTab(el.querySelector('.chrome-tab-current'));
```

But you need to code the content panel (probably webview element) and its css manually.

---

Other alternative is using [electron-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-tabs). But when i tried using it, it created two tabs in the javascript when i call `tabGroup.addTab()`. So i can not recommend it.

Comment: chrome-tabs does not carry a unique id for us to map it to a BrowserView ?

Comment: @Vickmaniac, i think you can just add attributes, or use vue or angular to track the id and browserview.

Answer (score -3):

```
var shell = require('electron').shell;
event.preventDefault();
shell.openExternal('https://github.com');
```

Comment: @Ravindra Barthwal Webking, i just got this, i too facing same problem which could'nt make it

Comment: so can you update your code to open new tab in browser window ?

Comment: This just opens in an external browser - really not the same thing.